# On teaching Kolmogorov complexity with Python and the complexity of composed strings

Tags: turing-machines, kolmogorov-complexity, python

The setting of this question is a bit long-winded, but please bear with me.

This fall I will be lecturing a course on mathematical information theory, and on a few lectures we will be discussing [Kolmogorov complexity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) One of the challenges I face is that most of my students will most likely not be familiar or comfortable with an abstract definition of a Turing machine, and the schedule does not permit a tangent to defining finite automata etc.

My current idea is to replace an abstract Turing machine with Python3, i.e. there will be examples and some exercises where we try to produce various strings with Python3 code (with any extra packages not allowed, basically code golfing). I'm fairly confident that I will be able to deliver the fundamental idea with this, but I do have a concrete problem.

In the book *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by Michael Sipser we have some interesting results about Kolmogorov complexity (pp. 237-245) which I would like to go through in as much detail as the setting permits. In particular, I would like to prove Theorems 6.25 and 6.26 which state that "$K(xx) \leq K(x) + c$" and "$K(xy) \leq 2K(x) + K(y) + c$", respectively. The latter result in particular is fascinating, and cannot be improved (much) beyond a limit of the type

$$K(xy) \leq \log(K(x)) + K(x) + K(y) + c. $$

To my understanding the fact that we cannot improve the latter estimate to depend only linearly on $K(x)$ and $K(y)$ is due to the fact that the Turing machine producing the string $y$ needs to be informed how long the printout of $x$ is so that it knows where to continue. (Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not a specialist when it comes to Turing machines.)

But now we get to the heart of my problem, namely the following argument I could imagine a student making. Suppose I have two strings, $x$ and $y$, and two Python-programs, call them $P_x$ and $P_y$, producing these string, respectively. It doesn't seem far fetched that however these programs print their output, it would not add to the complexity more than a constant amount to instead first store the output to a variable and then print the said variable:

```
# Program Px
x = ""
...
x = x + "abc"
...
print(x)
```

```
# Program Py
y = ""
...
y = y + "cde"
...
print(y)
```

Now, having these programs of length $K(x)$ and $K(y)$ we could just append them to the same .py -file after changing the last line in $P_x$ from `print(x)` to `print(x,end='')`, which omits the printing of a newline character.

Now I have created a program with complexity below $K(x) + K(y) + c$, contradicting Theorem 6.26. I get the feeling that in this argument I'm actually using the conditional complexity $K(y|x)$ instead of $K(y)$, but I can't quite grasp what is the exact point of error.

> Where is my error and how would it be best explained?

Furthermore, any remarks on the general idea of teaching Kolmogorov complexity via limited Python code golfing are welcome.

Comment: Well, what happens if the string $y$ contains, say, a quotation symbol `"`?

Comment: @PålGD One of the central difficulties in the proof of the theorem is properly separating the encodings of $x$ and $y$ (and this is why we get the two times $K(x)$ factor or, also, the $\log K(x)$ factor in the improved bound). Here, the problem translates to having a quotation symbol in the string (since the symbol must be properly escaped).

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I will meditate on these. (And better yet, get my hands dirty and actually write down a few examples that make my error visible.)